# How to fill/blur the inside of bounding box in YOLO object detection?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, yolo, yolov4

I have used YOLOv4 to detect objects in an image now I want to blur those objects or superimpose black color inside the bounding box. How can I do that using OpenCV or some other library?

Comment: cv2.rectangle with thickness -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, -1)`

I just changed the width of the bounding box and it worked.

Thank you @micka